# jQuery speed when referencing objects and their descendants

Tags: javascript, jquery

With regards to speed and using resources, If i save the html of a page as a jquery object, such as:

```
var meHTML = $('html')
```

Should i then reference further objects as say

```
var someID = meHTML.find('#someID')
```

as opposed to

```
var someID = $('#someID')
```

Im sure its probably only minimal, but Im curious to find out what the differences may be.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at [the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L141) for a `$("#id")` call, you can see they enhanced a single ID selector alot by directly using `document.getElementById` and setting the length of the set to `1` manually.

[The source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/traversing.js#L19) for `.find`, however, is more expensive since the selector is passed through to Sizzle. Moreover, it checks for duplicates in the resulting set for example, which isn't necessary with an ID. It will come down to a longer and slower code path.

So, `$("#id")` should be faster.